# man page editor for text screen

Tags: linux, documentation, console, manpage

Do you know any editor for man(1) pages which work on text screen (terminal and console)? Searching the interned did not gave any useful results as the words are very common.

Or should I learn the details of the format and write it by hand?

Comment: man pages is based on `troff`. `man 7 man` gives the details

Comment: @phoxis maybe he wants to create man pages for his own software.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7707119/23118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it e.g. in `markdown` then convert it via e.g. `pandoc` to manpage format (`(t|g)roff`). Here is the fine manual: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html .

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Sure, go ahead and learn the format and write it by hand in a regular text editor.

On the other hand, the `perl` project uses a kind of universal markup called `pod` and then converts into manpages by running `pod2man`.

Answer (score 1):

Man pages are written in plain text with a simple markup language called `troff`.

Actually there are several related markup systems all supported by a set of commands ending in `roff`: `nroff`, `troff`,  and the all singing, all dancing super-set `groff`.

My Mac OS 10.5 systems has a nice summary of the history in `man 7 roff`.

As others have noted there are several tools around which can convert *other* markup formats to man pages.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write content as "reStructuredText" (simpler than wiki syntax) and use docutils to generate manpage from it.

See [this tutorial](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/generating-man-pages-from-restructuredtext.html).